# Default order on owner property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a shopping basket which has items in it. My class is *BasketItem < ActiveRecord::Base*.

A BasketItem *belongs_to :item*.

*Item* has many *item_tags*. It also has many tags *through* *item_tags*.

Tags have a key-value set up. The key can be things like "price", "perishable", "produce", etc. The "produce" key has values like "citrus fruit", "berry fruit", "melon fruit", "vegetable", "root", "fungus" and so on.

When pulling a basket, I want the items to come back in a default order of: all the fruits, fungus, then everything else.

In SQL, I'd do my joins and then add:

```
ORDER BY (
   CASE
   WHEN tags.value LIKE '%fruit%' THEN 0
   WHEN tags.value = 'Vegetable' THEN 1
   ELSE 2
   END)
```

I have tried:

```
has_many :tags, through: :produce
```

with a default scope of:

```
default_scope { order(tags: :desc) }
```

Just to see if I can access the tags, which I can't. In fact, looking at the SQL generate, it's straight up pulling from basket_items with no joins.

1) So how do I order on that tag relationship?
2) How do I get my CASE in there?
3) And how do I make that the default? (If it's not default_scope.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? Show your existing classes around your scopes and relations?

Comment: `default_scope { joins(item_tags: :tags)order(item_tags: { tags: :desc) } }` might work. I think you need to add the joins and then traverse the association in the order?

Comment: You can put an order by clause on the `has_many` `has_many :tags, -> { order(some_column: :desc) }, through: :produce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of Mike Heft's comment and cleaning up the syntax a bit, I ended up with:

```
default_scope {joins(:tags).order("CASE WHEN tags.name LIKE ...")}
```

And that created an SQL query that returns things in the right order.

(This ends up being scrambled again, because the code above that is just pulling the IDs for the product, and returning them in that order. I applied the same gag on that level and...still got them scrambled. So, while I still have to sort out who's responsible for what, it was a simple "join().order()".)